# Socket.IO: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined of handshake data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In our NodeJS project we use socket.io v0.9.11 (planning to update at least this year) + RedisStore. From time to time we have such error that crashes Node process:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

This happens at place when code tries accessing `socket.handshake.query` data for logging.

Maybe someone knows about this issue or experienced similar thing. What internal socket.io processes may set `socket.handshake` to `undefined`? I don't see any statements that may delete or set this to `undefined` in my code.

Comment: 2 things i might help with here, first, try to use `try` and `catch` statements to handle the error which is causing the crash, secondly, and in that specific case i would use `forever` to handle the auto start of any crashed node service, you may check it here https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash Auto restart is already handled in project. Also, I'll eventually add needed `try/catch` instructions. What I'm actually asking is what internal socket.io processes may set `socket.handshake` to `undefined`.